# How to get id attribute of clicked tr button element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jquery-click-event

I'm binding a click event to buttons created dynamically in a table of [class](https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda) `.lada-button`.

In the current setup creating a reference to the button using a class selector `Ladda.create( document.querySelector( '.ladda-button' ) );` triggers the submit transition only for the first button in the table. Instead of the button that has been clicked.

So in order to trigger it for the button that had been clicked, I tried getting the id of the clicked button which returns undefined for the `id` attribute:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var row in Model.Status)
    {
         <tr>
             <td style="visibility:hidden;" >@Html.Raw(row.ID)</td>            
             <td><button type="submit" data-style="expand-right" class="ladda-button"><span class="ladda-label">Update</span><span class="ladda-spinner"></span></button></td>
         </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

```js
$(".ladda-button").click(function () {
    var btnId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(btnId);
    var updateBtn = Ladda.create( document.querySelector( btnId ) );
    // Start loading
    updateBtn.start();
});
```

How can you get the id attribute of clicked tr button element?

Comment: How is your HTML layout? Maybe you need get the parent `$(this).parent().attr('id')`

Comment: You don't need jquery... just use `this.id` or the parent element's ID `this.parentElement.id`

Comment: well, maybe I'm wrong but it seems it's undefined because you don't have any id attribute on your button: <button type="submit" data-style="expand-right" class="ladda-button">

Comment: @Gatsbill the table rows containing the buttons are created dynamically so I haven't set an id attribute for them.

Comment: So what you want to get ???

Comment: I want to try to get a reference to the clicked button element, in order to create the `Ladda` object which references the clicked button. For example... `var updateBtn = Ladda.create( document.querySelector( this.id ) );`

Comment: I think the problem is in the `document.querySelector( btnId )` part. You have to prepend the id with "#" to indicate the selector is an id and not an element.

Comment: Ok I did try that like so.. `var updateBtn = Ladda.create( document.querySelector( '#' + this.id ) );` but got an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#' is not a valid selector`

Comment: well you have to make sure that you get the correct id as well, it cant be undefined or null. See answers how to grab closest tr reference

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery *closest* function.

You can see a simple example here

```
$("button").click(function(event) {
    alert($(this).closest("tr").attr("id"));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0pxswgt6/2/